# Python regex capture the group if has similar pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataset which has tweets but it's in the following form:

```
@ xxx _ yyy having trouble finding regex for this case #regex # python @stackoverflow # I _ got _ this
```

Now, if you see the data is not in the ideal form, where hashtags and twitter ids are in proper format. Now, for the purpose of sentiment analysis, I need to remove these hashtags and ids from the data.

Now, this is the regex I am using:

```
[@|#]\s*\S+\s*_\s*\S+|[@|#]\s*\S+
```

Now, this is not the perfect but it solves most of the problems. It matches **@ xxx _ yyy**,  **#regex**, **# python**,  **@stackoverflow**, and **# I _ got**. But the one problem here is instead of capturing the whole **# I _ got _ this**, it captures only **# I _ got**. And this is where I am stuck at.

For more information: [pythex](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5B%40%7C%23%5D%5Cs*%5CS%2B%5Cs*_%5Cs*%5CS%2B%7C%5B%40%7C%23%5D%5Cs*%5CS%2B&test_string=%40%20xxx%20_%20yyy%20having%20trouble%20finding%20regex%20for%20this%20case%20%23regex%20%23%20python%20%40stackoverflow%20%23%20I%20_%20got%20_%20this&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

I am looking for a regex which matches the string no matter how many *Undescores*(**_**) are in the string. It should match until the string after the last underscore.

I hope I am very clear in the problem statement. Kindly guide me here.

Comment: Use `[@#]\s*\S+(?:\s*_\s*\S+)*`, see https://regex101.com/r/jLiW6r/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
[@#]\s*\S+(?:\s*_\s*\S+)*
```

Or, a bit more precise, since `\S` also matches `_`:

```
[@#]\s*[^_\s]+(?:\s*_\s*[^_\s]+)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jLiW6r/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/jLiW6r/2)

**Details**

- `[@#]` - `#` or `@` char
- `\s*` -  0 or more whitespaces
- `[^_\s]+`  - 1 or more chars other than whitespace and `_`
- `(?:\s*_\s*[^_\s]+)*` - 0 or more sequences of

  - `\s*_\s*` - a `_` enclosed with 0 or more whitespaces
  - `[^_\s]+`  - 1 or more chars other than whitespace and `_`

Comment: hey @Wiktor, can you help me out in this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62307275/python-regex-capture-various-url-pattern-group?