# Python regex capture various url pattern groups

Tags: python, regex

I have dataset containing the string like this and I want to remove the all the urls from the it

`http://google.com having trouble finding regex https://google.com for this case http // google com / test some gibberish https // google . com / test / test1 great http.//google.org`

Now, I am using this regex pattern to find the all urls:

```
https?:?\s?\/\/\s?\S+
```

Now, ideally, it should capture all the urls such as in this case,

- `http://google.com`
- `https://google.com`
- `http // google com / test`
- `https // google . com / test / test1`
- `http.//google.org`

but with the regex pattern I have, it is capturing only

- `http://google.com`
- `https://google.com`
- `http // google`
- `https // google`

Link to [Regex](https://pythex.org/?regex=https%3F%3A%3F%5Cs%3F%5C%2F%5C%2F%5Cs%3F%5CS%2B&test_string=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%20having%20trouble%20finding%20regex%20https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%20for%20this%20case%20http%20%2F%2F%20google%20com%20%2F%20test%20some%20gibberish%20https%20%2F%2F%20google%20.%20com%20%2F%20test%20%2F%20test1%20great%20http.%2F%2Fgoogle.org&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

Comment: @anubhava, yeah currently the data I have, it has urls with the space in it. That's why it's getting my nerves.

Comment: Perhaps `https?:?\s?//\s?\S+(?:\s+\.?\s?com)?(?:\s?/\s?(?!http)[^\s/]+)*` https://regex101.com/r/qhwmFZ/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, your solution worked, but partially. Just one problem is if the url has any other extension apart from **com**, such as **org**, then it doesn't capture. I have updated my question above.

Comment: You could list all the accepted extensions in an alternation `(?:com|org)` and match either a dot or colon in a character class `[.:]` See https://regex101.com/r/czMwAT/1

Comment: Try `https?[:.]?\s?\/\/(?:\s*[^\/\s.]+)+(?:(?:\s*\.\s*[^\/\s.]+)*(?:\s*\/\s*[^\/\s]+)*|\s*\/\s*[^\/\s]+)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/syMCD7/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks once again, it worked like charm.

Comment: It appears you may simplify the pattern, I posted a simpler version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
https?[:.]?\s?\/\/(?:\s*[^\/\s.]+)+(?:\s*\.\s*[^\/\s.]+)*(?:\s*\/\s*[^\/\s]+)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/syMCD7/3).

**Details**

- `https?` - `http` or `https`
- `[:.]?` - an optional `:` or `.`
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
  -`\/\/` -  `//` char sequence
- `(?:\s*[^\/\s.]+)+` - (to match all domain name parts till the last `.` before TLD) 1 or more occurrences of

  - `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
  - `[^\/\s.]+` - 1 or more chars other than `/`, `.` and whitespace
- `(?:\s*\.\s*[^\/\s.]+)*` - 0 or more sequences of

  - `\s*\.\s*` - a dot enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
  - `[^\/\s.]+` - 1 or more chars other than `/`, `.` and whitespace
- `(?:\s*\/\s*[^\/\s]+)*` - 0 or more sequences of

  - `\s*\/\s*` - a `/` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
  - `[^\/\s]+` - 1 or more chars other than `/` and whitespace

Answer (score -1):

The joy of Python: practically anything you can imagine already exists as a library.

See https://github.com/madisonmay/CommonRegex

This package provides many regex formats (including URL and many others) so you don’t have to rediscover how to.

Comment: why would I use a separate package, if same thing can be done using default packages? also if this is not answer but suggestion then you should not put it as an answer.